# Turkish Airline didn't allow me to board due to covid restrictions

Tags: covid-19, turkish-airlines, kyrgyzstan, denied-boarding, estonian-citizen

Last month I planned to take a trip
Helsinki-Istanbul-Bishkek through Turkish Airlines. Usually we as Estonian citizens don't need a visa to enter Kyrgyzstan but due to Covid I wanted to be sure and asked a representative in Bishkek who is the consul of Estonia over there. She confirmed that Estonian citizens have no restrictions entering Kyrgyzstan.

When I was about to board my flight in Helsinki, I was told that due to my nationality I was not allowed to board. The staff told me they will reimburse my flight 100%. They were nice and friendly but after a few e-mails they stopped replying and now they totally ignore me. I contacted Turkish airlines officials in Turkey and they said that it is my fault that I did not check the requirements and therefore they have a right to not pay me anything.

But the staff in Helsinki assured me that they are going to pay me back the whole sum! What can I do?

Comment: Is it possible that the Estonian consul misinterpreted your question? Did you specifically ask her about entry restrictions due to Covid? Despite what the airline staff said when you were denied boarding, it’s vanishingly unlikely you will get anything from Turkish airlines since the mistake was not theirs.

Comment: When exactly did you plan to travel? It is difficult to find correct and comprehensive historical information about covid related restrictions, but if what I found is correct, foreign citizens were usually not allowed to enter before September 24th and after that only with a recent and negative corona test.

Comment: I did ask specifically about covid restrictions. I take the blame for not investigating further and blindly believing the consul tho. My ticket was for 28th September. Now i know that Estonian nationals are not allowed (kinda funny tho we have one of the smallest cases in the whole europe). My question was more about the airline reinbursment.

Comment: Did you use a credit card to pay? Did you purchase travel insurance? Those **might** be helpful

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING: This answer doesn't necessarily mean that OP was not allowed to enter Kyrgyzstan on 28 Sep 2020.**

[Skyscanner](https://www.skyscanner.net/travel-restrictions/kyrgyzstan/29475318) suggests that Estonian nationals are not allowed to enter Kyrgyzstan due to Covid-19 restrictions as of 23 Oct 2020.

> Passengers are not allowed to enter Kyrgyzstan.
>
> -This does not apply to:
>
> - nationals of Kyrgyzstan;
> - passengers with a permanent residence permit issued by Kyrgyzstan;
> - nationals of Armenia, Austria, Azerbaijan, Belarus, Belgium, China (People's Rep.), Georgia, Germany, Iceland, Ireland (Rep.), Italy,
>   Japan, Kazakhstan, Korea (Rep.), Kuwait, Latvia, Liechtenstein,
>   Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malaysia, Pakistan, Portugal, Qatar, Russian
>   Fed., Slovenia, Sweden, Switzerland, Turkey, Turkmenistan, United Arab
>   Emirates and Uzbekistan;
> - British nationals;
>
> ...

Comment: Did that apply "last month"?  How about transiting through Turkey?

Comment: The question is not what is currently allowed, but what was allowed when OP intended to fly on September 28th.

Comment: @gerrit As far as I understand, the restrictions were stricter last month. If I find out some clear information, I will edit my answer. I haven't seen any information related to transits.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo OP mentioned the exact date after I did post this answer. If I find out more information, I will edit the answer.

Comment: @ahmedus I am fully aware that OP didn't tell exactly when he wanted to travel and I asked about it and told him that without this information, his question can't be answered. That was before you posted your answer. Still, this is not an answer to OPs question. The current rules are in no case relevant and based on OPs comment, your answer obviously lead him to believe that the airline was right. At best, your answer is just misleading and not plain wrong. It does in any way not contain any information helping OP to solve his problem.